# Why am I not getting the image background in my div?

Tags: html

The following in mystyle1.css works great on my laptop at home, I get a div with a starry-sky background.

However, when I upload it to my GoDaddy webpage, no starry sky!

The folders are arranged the same, in the folder with the html files are the subfolders css, images, mp3, php

Can anyone tell me why this works at home but not on my host?

```
#div-alien {
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;   
    /*temporary text styles below*/
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    background-image: url("../images/starrysky1.jpeg");
    background-color: #cccccc;
    height: 500px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    border:3px; 
    border-style:solid; 
    border-color:#FF0000;

}
```

Comment: Does the 'network' tab of your browser's dev tools show a 404 when it tries to load the image?

Comment: No, images are all in place. The alien does show, put in by <img src="images/alien1.png" but no nice starry bg!

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand the question. Just checked. Network shows status 200 for mystyle1.css

Comment: No, not for mystyle1.css; for `starrysky1.jpeg`.

Comment: no, no other comments, just 2 lines about mystyle1.css, both Status 200

Comment: One thing: I have lots of different divs. In the Inspector tab, when I click on say, div id="div-with-bg" I see it on the right. But, when I click on div-alien, I only see my plain div on the right. Something is not working right!

Comment: Well, just now I opened the webpage and, lo and behold, the div-alien had a starry background!! It's a miracle!